# Linux page cache / buffer cache - unified or not

Tags: linux, caching

As far as i've read discussion on LKML, around 2010, thus ~ 2.2.x kernel there was supposed to be a great unification of pagecache and buffer cache.

1. Did it happen ? Do we have SINGLE memory space referenced by both?

I've browsed through [filemap.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/filemap.c) and [buffer.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/buffer.c) and unfortunately had not found ANY patches that would actually merge two buffers. Nothing actually indicating that any unification after 2010 took place. Perhaps i've missed something.

1. LKML is very usernotfriendly - anyone knows site simmilar to lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/ that has clear "tree like" overview of whole some-thread in LKML and does not loose subthreads that emerge to another branch, and first of all allow flat view of multiple messages (without tiring clicking)?
2. pagecache vs buffer. Lets imagine that they are separated. Can someone explain what is main reason we need to have two of them, instead of for example focusing on one? 
   Say - buffer caching, that caches every IO, FIFO or even takes most frequently used sectors into consideration and caches them separately from queue.
   Or quite opposite, just page cache, leave write ahead, read 1+X read ahead sectors from slow IO into memory, decide what stays according to free memory and some other fancy algorithm?
3. Lets imagine that buffer cache and page cache are unified. How this unification actually helps(still leaving two different source files), given that buffer cache stores pointers to memory cached pages? Eventually both serve same purpose - store X data in memory. Only obvious difference would be -buffer-buffering with read ahead, several "predicted" neraby sectors, and -cache- store in memory frequently demanded io sectors.